# Is there a version of 'CONTAINS' function in SQLITE other than 'LIKE'?

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, csv

I'm trying to find totals for each number in the range of 1 to 7. But the data contains different combinations of these numbers. For e.g. 1; 2; 3,7; 1,2,3 and so on. I want to find the total number of times each number pops up. What I essentially want is a code for SQLite that's goes like:

```
select <fields>, count(*)
from tablexyz
where <field> contains '2' (and '3','4',... individually)
```

When I input "where  like '2%'" and such, it only gives me all series that start with 2 but negates series that starts with 1 but contains 2.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please provide example source data and example output that you would expect from that source data.

Comment: What do you mean by `CONTAINS` ? That's not a standard SQL operator. In T-SQL for example it's a free-text-search operator that requires FTS indexes to provide decent performance. You could use `LIKE '%2%'` to find fields that contain 2 anywhere. If you want an operator that will split the data and identify specific fields though, you're using the wrong design. You should create a separate table to hold that data. SQLite is an embedded database without a lot of bells and whistles. It doesn't even have types, much less arrays

Comment: An embedded DB is run by your own application. If you try to do things it can't handle efficiently, you end up wasting time compared to just reading the data and parsing it in your code. That's what happens in this case. SQLite can't index those values so it has to scan all of them. It would be better if you just read all those strings and used eg a regex to check for individual values

Answer (score 1):

> *I want to find the total number of times each number pops up*

Your sample code and the solution you say you want don't exactly align. The closest I can think of is

```
with  t (txt) as -- a sample record from your table

(select '1; 2; 3,7; 1,2,3'),

t2 (num) as  -- a lookup table we can create for range of numbers 1-7

(select 1 union all
 select 2 union all
 select 3 union all
 select 4 union all
 select 5 union all
 select 6 union all
 select 7)

select t2.num, length(t.txt) - length(replace(t.txt,t2.num,'')) as num_occurence
from t2
left join t on t.txt like '%' || t2.num || '%'
```

**Outputs**

```
+-----+---------------+
| num | num_occurence |
+-----+---------------+
|   1 | 2             |
|   2 | 2             |
|   3 | 2             |
|   4 | NULL          |
|   5 | NULL          |
|   6 | NULL          |
|   7 | 1             |
+-----+---------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=75a83b6015844bb5b90a149f44469347)**

Answer (score 0):

Using the solution below, you can build a "table" of the numbers 1 to 7, then join it to your source data table to count if the number occurs in that row, then sum it together.

#### Query

```
WITH
    sample_data (nums)
    AS
        (SELECT '1,2,3,4,5,6' 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '3,4,5,6' 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '1,2,7,6' 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT '6' ),
    search_nums (search_num)
    AS
         (VALUES(1)
          UNION ALL
          SELECT search_num+1 FROM search_nums WHERE search_num<7)
select search_num, sum(count_of_num) from (
SELECT s.nums,
       n.search_num,
       case
         instr(s.nums, n.search_num)
         when 0 then 0
         else 1
       end as count_of_num
  FROM sample_data  s, search_nums n
) group by search_num;
```

#### Result

```
search_num  sum(count_of_num)
1           2
2           2
3           2
4           2
5           2
6           4
7           1
```